# É aceitável fazer uma pergunta pedindo opiniões sobre um código e como deixá-lo mais eficiente?

Tags: suporte, escopo-do-site

Como iniciante, ainda cometo muitos deslizes que podem deixar meus códigos extensos. Por isso, opiniões de como condensá-lo são extremamente bem-vindas. É aceitável postar perguntas desse tipo?

Comment: Pedindo opniões não, pois a pergunta tem uma grande chance de ser fechada. Uma revisão de código em um ponto especifico ou com um objetivo ex: eliminar certos if ou chamadas de outros métodos é permitida tem alguns exemplos

Comment: [off-topic] Brincou! O [meta-tag:escopo] está todo desorganizado... {adicionei as duas tags porque [meta-tag:no-tópico] contém a pergunta MASTER(?)}

Comment: Douglas, isto aqui é tipo importante: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Se souber inglês, isto é mais importante ainda: http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @brasofilo E se [meta-tag:no-tópico] fosse sinônimo de [meta-tag:escopo]?

Comment: @bfavaretto, acho que sim, creio que "escopo" é o que aparece em algumas mensagens de suspensão/fechamento e o mais mencionado em comentários.

Comment: @rray "grande chances de acabar sendo fechada" não é um bom argumento numa pergunta no Meta sobre o escopo do site. É justamente aqui que nós podemos discutir se algo deve passar a ser aceito ou rejeitado.

Comment: [Por que duvidas baseadas em opiniões/trocar ideias sobre códigos não são aceitas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4210/91)